# Strange Errors in a For Loop

Tags: objective-c

Hello there fellow coders.
I have been learning my way around GLKit over the past few weeks. I found this very helpful series of tutorials on how to set-up a basic 2D graphics engine found [here](http://games.ianterrell.com/how-to-draw-2d-shapes-with-glkit-part-2/).

When I followed the first chunk of 'Iteration 5' code something strange happened. The for loop in the `updateVertices` method comes up with compiler errors. Those errors are shown here.

[image: Errors]

Here's the class code in it's entirety.

```
//
//  Elipse.m
//  EmptyGLKit
//
//  Created by C-R on 8/6/13.
//  Copyright (c) 2013 C-R. All rights reserved.
//

#import "Ellipse.h"

#define ELLIPSE_RESOLUTION 64;
#define M_TAU (2*M_PI)

@implementation Ellipse

-(int)numVertices {
    return ELLIPSE_RESOLUTION;
}

-(void)updateVertices {
    for (int i = 0; i < ELLIPSE_RESOLUTION; i++) {
        float theta = ((float)i) / ELLIPSE_RESOLUTION * M_TAU;
        self.vertices[i] = GLKVector2Make(cos(theta)*radiusX, sin(theta)*radiusY);
    }

}

-(float)radiusX {
    return radiusX;
}

-(void)setRadiusX:(float)_radiusX {
    radiusX = _radiusX;
    [self updateVertices];
}

-(float)radiusY {
    return radiusY;
}

-(void)setRadiusY:(float)_radiusY {
    radiusY = _radiusY;
    [self updateVertices];
}

@end
```

I've tried closing and reopening the project, cleaning the code, rebooting Xcode, all without success.

To my knowledge that for loop is completely acceptable and has been in several other projects of mine.

Comment: This is not related to Xcode.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a typo (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/167342/close-all-the-typo-questions)

Comment: But I didn't know it was about a typo until it was pointed out.

Comment: I'll close it directly.

Comment: I'd say its a syntax error that isn't too easy to understand from the affect it has, not a spelling style typo.

Comment: Such things can be devilishly hard to figure out, until you've seen them a few times.  It helps to *very carefully* consider the error messages and try to trace the point where the compiler first got confused, then look at everything feeding in at that point.  (Another difficult one is when a .h file is missing a `;` after the last declaration in the file -- depending on where it's included it can produce no error message at all or some very confusing ones.  And mismatched `{}` in an include is also a trick to figure out.)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your `#define` line has a `;` at the end. This isn't correct and should be removed. The `#define` is basically substituted into the code for compilation so the end result is an if statement with too many `;` characters in it.

Comment: Thank you very much. Looks like I need more caffeine! I'll accept your answer ASAP. :)